# Dados inseridos no SQLite3 não são mostrados na aplicação PyQT4

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

Fiz uma pequena aplicação desktop PyQt4 onde faço a inserção de dados no db sqlite3, mas quando vou consultar esses dados que foram inseridos anteriormente, eles não constam na tela de visualização dos mesmos, somente quando saio da aplicação e entro novamente pra fazer a consulta é que os dados aparecem. Não consigo identificar porque isso está acontecendo, alguém poderia me ajudar neste caso? Abaixo, parte do código de inserção dos dados no DB.

```
sql_ins_dados_q = "INSERT INTO quinas(concurso,data_sorteio,bola_1,bola_2,bola_3,bola_4,bola_5,arrecadacao,ganhadores_quina,rateio_quina,ganhadores_quadra,rateio_quadra,ganhadores_terno,rateio_terno) 
                   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

while i < len(trt_htm_q.concursos):
    insere_dados_q.cur.execute("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
    insere_dados_q.cur.execute(sql_ins_dados_q,(trt_htm_q.concursos[i],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+1],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+2],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+3],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+4],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+5],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+6],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+7],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+8],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+9],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+10],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+11],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+12],
                                                trt_htm_q.concursos[i+13]))
    i += 14
    c += 1
insere_dados_q.conn.commit()
insere_dados_q.cur.close()
insere_dados_q.conn.close()
```

Comment: Acho muito difícil conseguirem te ajudar sem verem nada do seu código - [leia isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Você consegue fazer uma conexão pelo prompt ao db logo que fizer a inserção, para ver se os dados estão lá? (antes de fechar o programa)

Comment: Daniel, fiz tudo pelo pyqt e nem sei como faria essa conexão via prompt.

Comment: Daniel, editei a pergunta colocando a parte do código de inserção dos dados no DB.

Comment: Então os dados são exibidos na aplicação, basta reabrí-la, correto? Se sim, o erro não estará na inserção dos dados, mas sim na forma como você está exibindo-os, necessitando, nesse caso, do código do QT4.

Comment: Coloque o código do pyqt, como indicado pelo Anderson... ;)

Comment: Pessoal verifiquei que o problema não é com relação à consulta dos dados que foram inseridos, me desculpem. O problema ocorre quando vou manipular esses dados tipo, algumas estatísticas, verifiquei que quando rodo por exemplo os nr pares/impares mais sorteados, os dados divergem quando fecho e abro a aplicação novamente. Então o problema está ai. Vou verificar a questão de abrir/fechar o banco de dados, pode ser isso né.